# Overriding init methods in TableViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

`iOS` newbie question: I have a `UITableViewController` with a navigation controller. I need to add an edit button to that controller. The table view controller is accessed from a tab controller. I have read several posts that suggest overriding the `initWithNibName` method. While this makes sense, I'm not understanding where/when this overridden method gets called or what I need to do force it to be called.

In other words, when I override this method, I get a successful build but the method never gets called and the code seems unreachable. What have I possibly left out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `initWithNibName` is not called, then your view controller is probably loaded from a storyboard file. In that case, you have to override `initWithCoder:` instead.

Comment: Super answer... Follow him